# How can I use SSL encryption in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, ssl

I have simple application from this tutorial: [WCF 4 Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

How can I implement some encryption? Something like HTTPS (SSL?).

Example code from tutorial.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Step 1 of the address configuration procedure: Create a URI to serve as the base address.
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service");

        // Step 2 of the hosting procedure: Create ServiceHost
        ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);

        try
        {


            // Step 3 of the hosting procedure: Add a service endpoint.
            selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(ICalculator),
                new WSHttpBinding(),
                "CalculatorService");


            // Step 4 of the hosting procedure: Enable metadata exchange.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Step 5 of the hosting procedure: Start (and then stop) the service.
            selfHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
            selfHost.Close();
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ce)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
            selfHost.Abort();
        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you hosting the WCF service - using the WCF built-in TCP or HTTP bindings, or through something like IIS?

Comment: It's all like in this tutorial.

Comment: You should first understand what configuration is your service using and be able to describe it in your question. Why should we read whole tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use transport security. See [HTTP Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734679.aspx). It describes how to configure SSL for both self-hosted and IIS-hosted services.

If all you need is encryption, then that's it. If you also want client authentication, then the client should use its own certificate which the service must accept.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have https in you IIS7 web site, you can try this:

1. Change enabled protocol value "https" to your advance settings of the web site.
2. Add bindings https port number eg: localhost:81
3. Add SSL Settings to your web site.

Then access your site using http://fullyqnameofyourcomputer:81
If you want to access the WCF Service with basic binding with the secure site, just make sure you add securicty mode (Not None) in you client config.

Comment: Is there a good reason to not use the default HTTPS port 443? I think the complicated step here is generating an SSL cert for IIS, though, if you don't already have one - I don't know if there's a version of the SelfSSL tool for IIS 7 (which does all the work for you in IIS 6).

Comment: @Rup: There is actually a self certificate for IIS7.  I'm just using it in my dev work thats why im using the 81 port, i have multiple sites that corresponds to my branches in TFS.

Comment: Neat, I hadn't seen that. Here's [ScottGu's blog about it](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx)