# WCF SSL connection configurations?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl-certificate

I wrote wcf service server and client aplications, both client and server works well with basic http binding.
Now I want to change configuration to use SSL for connection.
Is there any body that can explain how can I that and give an example about it

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Here is a really nice article about [just that](http://www.remondo.net/using-ssl-transport-security-wcf-basichttpbinding/) and a [nice post on Stack here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028033/how-can-i-use-ssl-encryption-in-wcf).

The key will be within your `Config` file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicSecure">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary.Echo.EchoService">
        <endpoint 
          address="https://localhost:8888/EchoService/" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicSecure" 
          contract="WcfServiceLibrary.Echo.IEchoService">
          <identity>
            <certificateReference 
              storeName="My" 
              storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" 
              findValue="f1b47a5781837112b4848e61de340e4270b8ca06" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

They thing to note here, is `security mode = "Transport"`  and the `CertificateReference`.  Those will be very, very important. You'll have to ensure your Ports are properly configured for this to work.

Keep in mind also `wshttpBinding` has this encryption enabled by default.

Good luck.

Comment: Just setting `<security mode="Transport">` did the trick for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi
This is a very simple and basic reference to using SSL on WCF Serice. 
I was in the same boat as you a while ago and my first question on SO was about HTTP/HTTPS Binding. I had a good discussion with one of the users on SO and they gave me a good idea about this
Have a look at this. I have the web config which is the main for configuration
[HTTP and HTTPS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608684/http-and-https-bindings)

Hope this helps.